# convert date in one format to another format

Tags: python, datetime

I have a date in the format '%Y-%M-%d' for example '2017-08-01', that I'd like to convert to the format '%m-%d-%y' for example '8-1-2017'.

Only relevant examples I've found have been in php unfortunately.

Comment: Why do you want to use regex? There are other python tools more able to parse dates. For example `datetime`

Comment: I should have used the word "format", I've changed that in the title

Comment: @orion24 done, try to experiment more with it and read about it https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

Comment: `from operator import itemgetter` and `'-'.join(itemgetter(1,2,0)(s.split('-')))` where `s` is the original date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.strptime("2017-08-01", '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%m-%d-%y')

datetime.strptime("2017-08-01", '%Y-%m-%d')
#output
datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 1, 0, 0)

#output final
'08-01-17'
```

In the first part `strptime` , you are defining how the date is to you. In other words, you are turning your string into a datetime type instance. Then in the second part `strftime` you are formatting it the way you wish it to be.

*Official definitions*

```
date, datetime, and time objects all support a strftime(format) method, 
to create a string representing the time under the control of an explicit format string.

Conversely, the datetime.strptime() class method creates
a datetime object from a string representing a date and 
time and a corresponding format string.
```